# arranging divs in the order shown in image

Tags: html, css

i need to arrange 5 div's inside a div with different widths and heights as shown in the image using only percentages in css..   So far i have done this. but not able to do the css properly. please help.!

html

```
<div id="blocks">
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
<div id="block3"></div>
<div id="block4"></div>
<div id="block5"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#blocks
{
    width:80%;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#block1
{
    height:66.67%;
    width:33.33%;
}
#block2
{
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%; 
}
#block3
{
    height:33.33%;
    width:33.33%;
}
#block4
{
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
}
#block5
{
    height:66.67%;
    width:33.33%;
}
```

[image: divs inside another div]

Comment: Shouldn't it be 66.66 instead of 73.33?

Comment: oops.. sorry.. yes it is 66.67% instead of 73.33%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use floats to style your HTML the way you want. Here is how I have done it: http://jsfiddle.net/Wp8ax/

HTML:

```
<div id="blocks">
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2"></div>
    <div id="block3"></div>
    <div id="block5"></div>
    <div id="block4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    outline: solid 1px black;
}
#blocks {
    width:80%;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #ffe;
}
#block1 {
    height:66.67%;
    width:33.33%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
#block2 {
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
    background: yellow;
    float: right;
}
#block3 {
    height:33.33%;
    width:33.33%;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
#block4 {
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
    background: cyan;
    float:left;
}
#block5 {
    height:66.67%;
    width:33.33%;
    background: magenta;
    float: right;
}
```

You need to use specific floats on elements and change the order of block4 and block5 in your HTML (or swap their styles in the CSS).

Comment: Great job. I was staring at the image and didn't figure out to simply use `float: right`.

Comment: @matewka - happens to everyone once in a while. remember to vote up! ;)

Comment: I did it at first place :)

Comment: @MarkSimpson - I have only used percentages as provided in the original question. The 500px height of `#blocks` was provided by the OP in his question. The solution would still work if the height was `auto` or `100%`, just edit my fiddle and try it out. Remember to add content to the divs since empty floats get collapsed.

Comment: @MarkSimpson Bare in mind it was there question and they said "Thank you soo much. that's what i was looking far." and marked it correct. This is what they was looking for. If they wanted it different I'm sure they would have said its wrong. As far as I can see this is the correct answer and I see no reason as to why it wouldn't be.

Comment: @MarkSimpson - I don't understand your comment. No version of my answer had fixed heights.

Comment: @Chandranshu Wow, I'm sorry. It turns out I mixed up my tabs. It was the solution by user user2549787 below that uses fixed heights, see http://jsfiddle.net/LBD6z/
Apologies for the mixup. My vote has been restored.

Comment: @MarkSimpson - I can rest at peace now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LBD6z/).

It's all done with `float` property.

Check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) for a better understanding on the float property.

Answer (score 1):

```
#blocks
{
    width:80%;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#block1,
#block2,
#block3,
#block4,
#block5 {
    position: absolute;
}
#block1
{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height:73.33%;
    width:33.33%;
    background: red;
}
#block2
{
    left: 33.33%;
    top: 0;
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
    background: blue;
}
#block3
{
    left: 33.33%;
    top: 33.33%;
    height:33.33%;
    width:33.33%;
    background: green;    
}
#block4
{
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
    background: orange;
}
#block5
{
    top: 33.33%;
    right: 0;
    height:73.33%;
    width:33.33%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

[image: div grid]

http://jsfiddle.net/v34pH/2/

Comment: thank you. can u please tell me what's the difference in using float and top,left,bottom,right ??

Comment: @KrishGowda Both work fine *in this case*, use whichever one you want.  :) In other cases, floats can be unstable, as they are affected by other content around them. Absolutely positioned blocks are more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I almost figured it out but the problem was always with the last two *divs*. I resolved it but I used bad and ugly `position: absolute` for the last div, so consider it as a *workaround*. I also had to switch places `#block4` and `#block5`.

The **HTML**:

```
<div id="blocks">
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2"></div>
    <div id="block3"></div>
    <div id="block5"></div>
    <div id="block4"></div>
</div>
```

the **CSS**:

```css
#blocks
{
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#blocks div
{
    outline: 1px solid;
    float: left;
}
#block1
{
    height:66.67%;
    width:33.33%;
}
#block2
{
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%; 
}
#block3
{
    height:33.33%;
    width:33.33%;
}
#block4
{
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#block5
{
    height:66.67%;
    width:33.33%;
}
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/dYgry/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply position: absolute to the overall div, then apply position relative to the sub-divs and position them accordingly.

e.g.

```
#block2{ position: absolute, left: 33.33%; top: 0; }
```

and so on . . .

Comment: whats is the difference in using float and position absolute with top,left attributes?

Comment: I personally find that position absolute is more controllable. With the layout you're proposing, floats might become a little tricky . . .

Answer (score 0):

That was fun :)
http://jsfiddle.net/JackKalish/6m2fQ/

```
#blocks
{
    width:80%;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    position:relative;
}
#block1
{   
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    height:73.33%;
    width:33.33%;
    background-color:#ffcccc;
}
#block2
{
    top:0;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
    background-color:#cffccc;
}
#block3
{

    position: relative;
    height:33.33%;
    width:33.33%;
    background-color:#cccffc;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:33.33%;
}
#block4
{
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    height:33.33%;
    width:66.67%;
    background-color:#ccffff;
}
#block5
{
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    height:66.66%;
    width:33.33%;
    background-color:#fccffc;
}
```